# Jagged array weird behaviour

Tags: java, arrays, jagged-arrays

Here is my jagged array which works perfectly fine during initialization:

```
   int a[][]=new int[5][];

   for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
   for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)
      {
       a[i]=new int[i+1];
       a[i][j]=j+1;
       System.out.print(a[i][j]);
      }
       System.out.println("");
   }
```

Gives me desired output :

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

But printing the same Array with loop just gives absurd output:

```
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
       {
       for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)
         {
          System.out.print(a[i][j]);
         }
          System.out.println("");
       }
```

Gives:

```
1
02
003
0004
00005
```

I cannot draw any conclusion. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code step by step? In particular have you checked what happens on this line: `a[i]=new int[i+1];`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating a new array in `a[i]` for each `j` during the initialization, and so erasing the previous value.
Here is the correction:

```
int a[][]=new int[5][];

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
  a[i]=new int[i+1];
  for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)
  {
    a[i][j]=j+1;
    System.out.print(a[i][j]);
  }
  System.out.println("");
}
```

As said in the comments, this error is trivial to solve with a debugger. It's time to learn how to use it ;)